# Automate posts in Google+ page through PHP/REST API

Tags: php, api, google-plus, google-oauth

I am working on web application which will help to schedule the post in social sites like facebook, twitter and google plus. As far as I researched in the internet, it seems Google is not providing any api for writing streams neither at Personal profile nor at Google Pages. And it has provided the api access only to limited apps like hootsuite, buffer. 
My question is, Is there any third party (even paid) APIs which will provide me this functionality ? Or, by any chance is it possible to request google for api access similar to the one, it provided for apps like hootsuite,buffer ?

Answer (score 0):

The Buffer API does allow you to schedule tweets automatically. It doesn't seem to support programmatically scheduling updates for other social media platforms, which is what I'm currently trying to do.